# Bash Script | Subtracting percentage from free disk space

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to subtract a percentage from a variable, preferable with floating point (11.3%) else 12%

```
freespace=100
subtract=$(($freespace-$freespace*.113))
```

Update 1:

Here is an explanation of what I am trying to accomplish: 
I am reducing my actual free space by 11.3%. if the file that I am copying is bigger than the subtracted free space then the script will prompt the user to create more space. bc command returns a floating-point. For this to work the output of bc must be without decimal points. df -m command outputs in megabytes and without decimal points. I don't you can compare 18000 MB with 120000.00 MB (bc output) in bash.

```
source="/some/dir"
destination="/some/dir

freespace="$(df -m "${destination}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')" 

reduced_percentage=".113" # minus 11.3 percent of actual freespace

reduced_freespace=$(bc <<< "$freespace * (1-$reduced_percentage)")

source_size="$(du -sm "${files}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}')"

if [[ "${reduced_freespace}" -lt "${source_size}" ]] ; then

read -r -n 1 -p "you do not have enough free space, create free space to continue..."  

elif [[ "${reduced_freespace}" -gt "${source_size}" ]] ; then

some commands

fi
done
```

Comment: Bash doesn't do floating point.

Comment: If you have python at hand, you could do `subtract=$(python -c "print($freespace * (1 - 0.113))")`. Feels like a bad solution, though...

Comment: `subtract=$( bc -q <<< "$freespace - $freespace * .113" )`

Comment: Please do not extend the question afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to learn the `bc` command.

Try this, and then read more [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc).

```
freespace=100
pct=.113
subtract=$(bc <<< "$freespace * (1-$pct)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for float calculation

```
$awk -v freespace=100 'BEGIN {print freespace-(freespace) * 0.113}' 
88.7
$
```